# tweetnacl returns no PRNG error in react native

Tags: react-native, tweet-nacl

I use nacl in react native

i just write down code below.

it returns no PRNG error in randombytes variable.

```js
  const test = nacl.box.keyPair();
```

here is my package.json too.

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've faced the same problem before. During research I discovered that `nacl` uses `nacl.randomBytes()` internally. However, the actual implementation differs depending on a platform you use it. For `node` it invokes [`crypto.randomBytes()`](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js/blob/master/README.md#naclrandombyteslength), which is not defined in ReactNative environment.

To get work `nacl` with ReactNative you need to provide the definition by yourself. You can do it by installing the [`react-native-get-random-values`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values) package and adding

```js
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
```

to the `index.js`

This will provide `nacl` with the definition for the `crypto.randomBytes()`.